# SnakeCase request body ignores format

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I need to configure my .NET core API to snake case, so in my startup I put:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() };
                })
```

and made two filters to swagger:

```
public class SwaggerSnakeCaseParameterFilter : IParameterFilter
    {
        private readonly SnakeCaseNamingStrategy _namingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy();

        public void Apply(OpenApiParameter parameter, ParameterFilterContext context)
        {
            parameter.Name = _namingStrategy.GetPropertyName(parameter.Name, false);
        }
    }
```

```
public class SwaggerSnakeCaseDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        private readonly SnakeCaseNamingStrategy _namingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy();

        public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
        {
            foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths.ToArray())
            {
                var apiDescription = context.ApiDescriptions.First(ad => "/" + ad.RelativePath == path.Key);
                var newKey = path.Key;
                foreach (var parameterDescription in apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Where(pd =>
                    pd.Source == BindingSource.Path))
                {
                    newKey = newKey.Replace(
                        "{" + parameterDescription.Name + "}",
                        "{" + _namingStrategy.GetPropertyName(parameterDescription.Name, false) + "}");
                }

                swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(path.Key);
                swaggerDoc.Paths.Add(newKey, path.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

But request body and response body still appears as `CamelCase` on `Swagger`.
What am I missing?
Parameters from query and route works fine.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Swashbuckle are you using? If you're using version 5, it uses `System.Text.Json` for serialization. Since you're using Newtonsoft, it will ignore anything you've configured for Newtonsoft serialization.

You can have Swashbuckle use Newtonsoft instead of `System.Text.Json` if you'd like:

- Add a reference to `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft`
- Add a call to `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` in `Startup.cs` after calling `AddSwaggerGen()`

The [Swashbuckle Readme](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft) includes more information about this if you're interested.